# Google Books errors on HTC Sensation on application launch

Tags: htc-sensation, google-play-books

Google Books Android crashes on loading, and whenever I have auto-sync enabled (which is hence very disruptive)

I always get the error twice:

> The application Books (process com.google.android.apps.books) has stopped unexpectedly. Please try again.

The actual stack trace shows the error to be:

> java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to create application com.google.android.app.TabletBooksApplication: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected a directory for path: /data/data/com.google.android.apps.books/cache/logs/null_account at android.app.ActivityThread...

I didn't consciously choose to install this application, it just seems to be part of the android application set.  I'm assuming the null_account bit is the problem but have no idea how to go about correcting this.

Comment: Are you signed in to your Google account on the device? That sounds like a dumb question, but it might be the reason for the 'null_account.'

Comment: Yep am signed in.  I use two google accounts on it (to access two different mail accounts).  Not sure if that has a bearing

Comment: I don't think it should, but when you signed into the second Google account, did it prompt you to choose which services to sync. I also have two accounts on my phone, but one of my accounts only syncs its email and contacts.

Comment: I may have done.  I'll investigate the settings on the second account (or just remove it for now)

Comment: Removed second acct, but still getting the same problem.  Also noted the last successful sync time was on 13th May.  Not sure if that was when I added the second account or if something else has triggered this behaviour.